# How do you make a simple SSRS representation of one row of data?

Tags: reporting-services

How do you make a simple SSRS representation of one row of data?

All of the SSRS Charts are groupings of data.  They are groupings of sets.   Even the simplest of bar charts seem to expect the developer to require to map database table.  What if you require something very basic?  What if you have a database with one row and five columns and you want that displayed in a simple bar chart with each bar only representing one value each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Data Bar, not a chart.  In the Toolbox, click on "Data Bar" not on "Chart".  Then just add the values.

And after you get it set up, there is actually a menu button to convert it to a chart.

Comment: the databar IS a chart

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add each column as a value.

In this example I just created a simple dataset with 3 columns (A, B and C) with values 1,2 & 3

I then added a basic column chart.

In the chart I just dragged each of the columns into the Values section of the chart and that's it.

The design looked like this

[image]

The output looked like this..

[image]